# Order of groups and dimensions of representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups, irreducible-representation

Show that if $H$ is an abelian subgroup of order $p$ of finite group $G$ of order $n$, then every irreducible representation is of dimension $\leq n/p$.

I'm really confused of how an order of a group can define the dimension of a representation. Anyone care to explain or give me some hints? Thank you in advance!\

This is a problem from Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach's book called Groups and Symmetries from Chapter two ''Representations of Finite Groups''

Comment: Is $p$ assumed to be a prime? Because then this is not really related to the subgroup itself.

Comment: A linear $F$-representation for $G$ of dimension $m$ is a homomorphism of $G$ into $\mbox{GL}_m(F)$. That's what is meant by the word "dimesnion" here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft p is not stated to be a prime

Comment: @Chris The dimension of a representations equals the dimension of the vector space it maps to , but then again is there a relation between the order of G and the dimension of a representation ?

Comment: Are you able to provide any context about the problem and where it came from? What facts you are allowed to use? Also, what have you tried so far? I am able to prove this using character theory, but the way you present it, it seems like you intend to only use representation theory.

Comment: @chris Yes sure , as stated at my now edited post, its from Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach's book called groups and symmetries. So far  the book involves representation theory on finite groups ,the regular representation ,some character theory and the induced representation .I tried to use the induced representation to solve the problem but in reality it lead me to nowhere

Comment: Do you also know Frobenius reciprocity?

Comment: A representation doesn't map into a vector space. It maps into the linear transformations of a vector space. The dimension of that vector space is the dimension of the representation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I,m afraid that I dont

Comment: @Chris Yes u r absolutely right

Comment: The (weaker) version of Frobenius I was thinking of using here states that if you restrict a representation to a subgroup and then induce back up, you get the original representation as a constituent.

Comment: Is the representation over an arbitrary field or is the representation over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Chris its over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The only stated proposition about induced representation is as follows: The support E of the induced representation $\pi^{\uparrow _G}$  is the vector space of sections of the projection $q:G\times _\pi F \mapsto G/H$ ,which is somewhat close to the version you refered to

Comment: And to briefly answer your question on the relationship between $|G|$ and the dimension of an irr. rep., they are definitely related. One cool result of Noboru Ito is that if $A$ is any normal, abelian subgroup of $G$, then the dimension of every irr. rep. divides $|G:A|$. This result makes use of Clifford's Theorem.

Comment: This post was already solved on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295076/frobenius-reciprocity-and-a-character-theory-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the notion of induced representations to prove this statement.  The biggest idea needed is the orthogonality of characters. Here is my proof:

Let $\Gamma$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$ into a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Let $\chi$ be the character of this representation. I claim that $\chi(1) \leq [\chi_H,\chi_H]$ where $\chi_H$ is the restriction of $\chi$ from $G$ to the abelian subgroup $H$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the inner product. We can prove this directly using the orthogonality relations of characters. Let $\chi_H = \sum_{i} n_i \psi_i$ where each $\psi_i$ is an irreducible $H$-character and each $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (Note that restricting irreducible characters can yield reducible characters.). We have that for $x \in H$,

$$
\chi(x)\bar{\chi}(x) = \sum_{i} n_{i}^{2}\psi_i (x) \bar{\psi_i}(x) + \sum_{i \neq j} n_i n_j \psi_i (x) \bar{\psi_j}(x)
$$
If we sum the rightmost expression over all $x \in H$, the sum on the right is zero by the Orthogonality Relations, so we have that

$$
\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x \in H} |\chi(x)|^2 = \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x \in H} \sum_{i} n_{i}^{2}\psi_i (x) \bar{\psi_i}(x) \geq \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x \in H} \sum_{i} n_{i}\psi_i (x) \bar{\psi_i}(x) = \sum_{i} n_i = \chi(1) $$

This implies the desired inequality that $\chi(1) \leq [\chi_H,\chi_H]$. We may then use this inequality to obtain that

$$
|H|\chi(1) \leq \sum_{x \in H} |\chi(x)|^2 \leq \sum_{x \in G} |\chi(x)|^2 = |G|[\chi,\chi] = |G|
$$
Where $[\chi,\chi] = 1$ since we assume $\chi$ is obtained from an irreducible representation. Now, $\chi(1) \leq |G:H| = \frac{n}{p}$ like you wanted to show.

This proof was outlined as Problem 2.9 in the Isaacs' book on character theory, and that's where this came from. If I used any confusing notation, let me know and I will clarify.

Comment: Im sry but Im a bit confused on how u concluded $\chi(x)\overline{\chi(x)}=...$

Comment: $\chi(x)\overline{\chi(x)} = (\sum_i n_i \psi_i(x))\overline{(\sum_j n_j\psi_j(x)}) = \sum_i \sum_j n_i n_j \psi_i(x) \overline{\psi_j(x)} = \ldots$.

Comment: oh yeah got it !

Comment: Thanks great solution and understandable !